# Structure Firebase data to return array of objects

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

What is the best way to structure firebase database so that querying just one endpoint i.e `admin.database().ref('categories').once()` returns me a json of the form

```
{
  "categories": [
    {
      "-ky1": {
        "name": "Profile",
        "id": "-ky1",
        "sections": [{
          "-ky1a": {
            "name": "section1",
            "id": "-ky1a",
            "-ky1a1": {
              "name": "field1",
              "id": "-ky1a1"
            }
          },
          "-ky1b": {
            "name": "section2",
            "id": "-ky1b",
            "-ky1b1": {
              "name": "fieldA",
              "id": "-ky1b1"
            }
          }
        }]
      }
    },
    {
      "-ky2": {
        ...
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

where ideally, I get back an array of nested objects.

Comment: You can just store that JSON in Firebase and retrieve it. What's the problem you have when implementing this?

Comment: If you're new to using NoSQL databases and are trying to learn the ropes, I recommend reading [NoSQL data modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/) and watching [Firebase for SQL developers](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLl-K7zZEsYLlP-k-RKFa7RyNPa9_wCH2s).

Comment: in the json example provided, it contains and array of nested objects which nests an arrays of objects. As firebase doesn't allow us to store an array of objects, I have stored it as a group of nested objects. However, when I retrieve it, the nested objects will not be an array and thus not sorted. I'd like to read a top level object and receive it of the form above so that it simplifies processing on my front-end. i.e it just displays the information without any additional processing.

Comment: There is a **recommendation** to use push IDs for collections, instead of array indices. But the Firebase Database technically works fine with arrays too, they just often lead to problems down the line. With your JSON the Firebase Database will store the array under `categories` as nested objects with sequential numeric keys. The Firebase SDKs will usually convert this back to an array when you retrieve the data. So it should work just fine. Can you show the code that you're using to read this data structure back from the database and what problem you're having with it.